# What are typical values to use for alpha and beta in Latent Dirichlet Allocation?

Tags: prior, dirichlet-distribution, topic-models

Specifically in the case where I don't know anything about the documents I'm working with. I'm looking a specific number or number range.

Answer (score 4):

Typical value of alpha which is used in practice is 50/T where T is number of topics and value of beta is 0.1 or 200/W , where W is number of words in vocabulary.

Comment: where do you get the 200/W from? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Griffiths and Steyvers (2004) suggest a value of 50/k (where k is number of topics) for α and 0.1 for δ. (They use δ rather than beta to refer to the other hyperparameter).

*Griffiths TL, Steyvers M (2004). “Finding Scientific Topics.” Proceedings of the National
Academy of Sciences of the United States of America, 101, 5228–5235.*